# Trouble with field-input accepting single quotes for %windows in SAS

Tags: sas, macros, window

I have the following code where users will be presented with the following window and they are to enter a text

Code:

```
%let study_code=;

%macro startme ;
%global study_code;

%window first
#3 @45 'Electronic Filing System' color=blue ////
@20 'Study code:' color=black  +2 study_code 30 color=green required=yes attr=underline //
 @10 '**************** Hit ENTER to begin ******************' color=green
;
%display first ;

%let study_code_new=%sysfunc(strip(%nrbquote(&study_code)));
%put &study_code_new.;
%mend;


%startme;
```

Window presented when run:

[image: Image 1]

I type `123`, hit `Enter` and it outputs `123` in the logs as expected:

[image: Image 2]

However, if a user enters `123"` by accident in the field, I am presented with the single quote error:

```
ERROR: Literal contains unmatched quote.
ERROR: The macro STARTME will stop executing.
```

How do I prevent SAS from reading `"` as code and treat it as literal string? I want to capture it in `study_code_new` macro variable so that I can tell the user that they have mistyped it.

Comment: Few people will be able to run this obsolete code and help you. In Enterprise Guide, this is replaced by prompts. It gives you comparable possibilities. And it allows you to require input to be numerical.

Comment: Thank you @DirkHorsten, sounds interesting! Will explore this option. Is this programmatically set up, or can it be set up through a GUI in Enterprise Guide?

Comment: In an EGuide project, you can assign prompts to tasks and programs in the project by editing their properties. The prompts them selves are defined for the whole the project, not the individual task. That might be strange at first, but it has the advantage that if you run multiple steps having the same prompt, you only have to answer the same question once. For advanced features, google for "Cascading Prompts in E-Guide".

Answer (score 1):

It is not the %WINDOW command or the %DISPLAY command that is the issue.  It is the code that you write that uses the macro variable's value.  You need to add macro quoting.

So first immediately add macro quoting to the macro variable populated by the %DISPLAY statement call.

```
%window first
  #3 @45 'Electronic Filing System' color=blue 
  #7 @20 'Study code:' color=black  +2 study_code 30 color=green
         required=yes attr=underline 
  #9 @10 '**************** Hit ENTER to begin ******************' color=green
;
%display first ;
%let study_code=%superq(study_code);
```

Then make sure to keep the macro quoting on any macro variable you derive from it (at least until you are sure it no longer needs the macro quoting).

```
46   %window first
47     #3 @45 'Electronic Filing System' color=blue
48     #7 @20 'Study code:' color=black  +2 study_code 30 color=green required=yes attr=underline
49     #9 @10 '**************** Hit ENTER to begin ******************' color=green
50   ;
51   %display first ;
52   %let study_code=%superq(study_code);
53   %let study_code_new=%qsysfunc(strip(&study_code));
54   %put &=study_code &=study_code_new;
STUDY_CODE= 123" STUDY_CODE_NEW=123"
```

Comment: Hi @Tom, it works and it's great! Just to confirm, if you use `%sysfunc()` instead of `%qsysfunc()`, the macro quoting disappears?

Comment: Yes.  %sysfunc() unquote the result. %qsysfunc() quotes the result.